# unable to retrieve JSON parameters by PHP from backbone

Tags: javascript, php, rest, backbone.js

I save my backbone model with no id therefore it uses the POST protocol to send parameters to my REST API. However I'm unable to catch these parameters, the PUT works just fine and updates the DB but POST method seem to cause problem. One thing I have noticed is that I can catch string parameters but integer parameters are returning as undefined.

my php

```
if($request_method == 'POST') {
$post_data = file_get_contents("php://input"); 
$post_data = json_decode($post_data, TRUE);
echo $post_data['name'];
}
```

backbone code

```
createdata: function(event){
    var newModel = new App.Models.Question({name:$("#_name").val(), surname:$("#_surname").val(), age:$("#_age").val()});
    newModel.save({},{
        success: function (model, response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (model, response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },      
            wait: true
        }

    );

    console.log(this.myCollection.toJSON());

},
```

Comment: Can you say what's the result of `console.log(newModel.attributes)` and `print_r($_POST)` on POST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while I have completed this project but still I wanted to post the code that was working fine for me.

```
createdata: function(event){
            var newModel = new App.Models.Quiz({ 
                name:$("#name").val(), 
                surname:$("#surname").val(), 
                age:$("#age").val()});

            newModel.save({wait:true},{
                success: function (model, response) {
                        $("#blanket").hide();
                        $("#create_popup").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (model, response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },      
                });
            this.personCollection.add(newModel);
            console.log(this.quizCollection.toJSON());
        },
```